# Can I set the working directory based on the name of the IntegrationTest?

Tags: maven, junit, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have my `maven-failsafe-plugin` configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>none</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                </includes>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/integration-test/</workingDirectory>
                <skipTests>${skipITs}</skipTests>                    

             </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now what I want to do, is have each of my integration tests run in a different directory in the target folder - so that I can check the logging for each one.

Is that possible - for example, something like:

`<workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/integration-test/${integration.test.name}</workingDirectory>`

Comment: I don't think you can do that using fail-safe plugin. You could however redirect your logs to stdout. Since there is a different output file for each test, you would be able to segregate your loglines.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`redirectTestOutputToFile`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) to true to redirect output to a file for each test with the result having an output file for each test which looks like this:

```
reportsDirectory/testName-output.txt
```

The reportsDirectory is defined by `reportsDirectory` configuration which is by default set to `${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports`.